# Problems about "boundary conditions and topology"

Tags: condensed-matter, boundary-conditions, gauge, wilson-loop, lattice-gauge-theory

In the book *Field Theories of Condensed Matter Physics* by Fradkin

In Page 311, when discussing the effects of boundary conditions on $Z_2$ lattice gauge theory, in the weak coupling phase, Fradkin says,

> for a system with
> an open boundary the axial gauge condition (such as $σ^1_z = 1$) completely and
> unambiguously fixes the gauge and defines the state

Then about periodical boundaries, he says

> Since the Wilson loop operators are products of $σ^z_j$ link operators, in the $g = 0$ limit $Wγ1 = ±1$ and $Wγ2 = ±1$. Hence we find four inequivalent versions of the weak-coupling state, and conclude that on a torus the axial gauge condition does not completely specify the state

1. I could not understand why in open boundary condition, we can impose axial gauge while in periodical condition, we cannot.
2. The Wilson loop is defined on direct lattice while 't Hooft loop is defined on dual lattice. So I could not understand how the writer says

> We can also define magnetic 't Hooft operators on non-contractible loops

Answer (score 0):

For question 1, the point is that closed wilson loops form gauge-invariant objects that cannot be gauged to be trivial. In periodic boundary conditions (e.g. for the square lattice on a torus), the wilson lines that travel all around one of the torus directions form wilson loops that cannot be gauged to triviality. In the case of the torus, there are two such directions, so there is a $2^2 = 4$-fold degeneracy of the ground state.

For this reason, gauge symmetry can (at most) eliminate all gauge links on a tree. Taking this idea to the limit, this is often called the `maximal tree gauge' in the literature

In lattice-QCD these types of operators have special names if you want to look them up more: if the wilson line runs in the time direction it's called the [Polyakov loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyakov_loop), if it runs in a compact spatial direction it excites states called Torelons.